# How to add padding top to first nav link item for mobile only

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move my first nav link (home icon) down so it doesn't get covered by the 'book free consultation' button above. It doesn't seem to apply the padding and not sure what I am doing incorrectly

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        
        #mega-menu-primary li.mega-menu-item:first-child{
        padding-top:20px !important;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header-navigation-wrapper">
   <nav class="primary-menu-wrapper" aria-label="Horizontal" role="navigation">
      <ul class="primary-menu reset-list-style">
         <div id="mega-menu-wrap-primary" class="mega-menu-wrap">
            <div class="mega-menu-toggle">
               <div class="mega-toggle-blocks-left"></div>
               <div class="mega-toggle-blocks-center"></div>
               <div class="mega-toggle-blocks-right">
                  <div class="mega-toggle-block mega-menu-toggle-block mega-toggle-block-1" id="mega-toggle-block-1" tabindex="0"><span class="mega-toggle-label" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="mega-toggle-label-closed">MENU</span><span class="mega-toggle-label-open">MENU</span></span></div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <ul id="mega-menu-primary" class="mega-menu max-mega-menu mega-menu-horizontal" data-event="hover_intent" data-effect="disabled" data-effect-speed="200" data-effect-mobile="slide_left" data-effect-speed-mobile="400" data-mobile-force-width="body" data-second-click="close" data-document-click="collapse" data-vertical-behaviour="accordion" data-breakpoint="1023" data-unbind="false" data-hover-intent-timeout="300" data-hover-intent-interval="100">
          
               <li class="mega-nav-menu-links mega-menu-item mega-menu-item-type-post_type mega-menu-item-object-page mega-menu-item-home mega-current-menu-item mega-page_item mega-page-item-2 mega-current_page_item mega-align-bottom-left mega-menu-flyout mega-menu-item-1521 nav-menu-links" id="mega-menu-item-1521"><a class="mega-menu-link" href="https://test.com/staging/4326/" tabindex="0"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
              ...
            </ul>
         </div>
      </ul>
   </nav>
   <!-- .primary-menu-wrapper -->
</div>
```

Image to show issue:

[image]

Comment: Can you code snippet so that we can help you.?

Comment: You missed one `}` - typo?

Comment: The code you have shown works fine (assuming the syntax error of the missing } is not actually in your code), and achieves the desired result. If it doesn’t for you in the context of your site - then you need to create a proper [mre] that actually illustrates the issue.

Comment: If padding doesn't work, try margin.

Comment: @Spectric your right, it's a margin-top, not padding

Answer (score 0):

Try using this if it works #mega-menu-primary > li:first-child {}

Answer (score 0):

I've edited this after another look at your code.

I've noticed your using the id selectorwhen you are looking for classes. The `#` looks for ids, but you want to look for classes, so use a `.` instead in your @media query

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .mega-menu-primary li.mega-menu-item:first-child{ 
        padding-top:20px !important; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a copy and paste error in SO. There is no missing }

Comment: Hi @BruceyBandit I had another look at your code and I saw more issues. I have edited my post and I hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin` like so:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    
    #mega-menu-primary li.mega-menu-item:first-child{
        margin-top:20px !important;
    }
    
}
```

`margin` helps push the nav down.